# Getting data in a loop from Axios promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a lot of data which needs to be compared with some remote data and then saved. A very basic example ...

Array:

```
[
  {
    "title" : "My title",
    "key": 12345
  },
  {
    "title" : "Some other title",
    "key": 54321
  },
...
]
```

A function which handles each of the objects from the array and another function which checks if the key exists before saving.

```
for(let v of array){
  myFunction(v);
}

const myFunction = async (val) => {
  const {title, key} = val;

  const options = {
   "url": `https://apicall.com/${key}` 
   "method": "POST",
   ...
  }

  const myVar = await anotherFunction(options)
  console.log(myVar)

  //compare remote and local data here
  //then proceed accordingly 

  ...
}

const anotherFunction = async (options) => {
  return await axios(options).catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

I need that value from axios before continuing, but I can't seem to get it to work synchronous. What is the best way to do something like that?

Comment: After each axios request you need to perform then operation. and in then you get the response where you compare your key
Eg -
 axios(options)
  .then((response) => {
      //compare the keys with the incoming response
    });

Comment: It's not clear if one request depends on the result of the previous. It not, `map()` over the array, passing each value to the async function. Then pass the returned array to `Promise.all()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just need to check a date of the remote data and if that differs from the local data, update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so by what i understood you have some local data and some remote data. You will compare both data on criteria of date and the remote element which has different date than that of local element you will update that local element.

Considering following is the **local data**.

```
[
  {
    "title" : "My title",
    "key": 12345,
    "date": "25-06-2019" 
  },
  {
    "title" : "Some other title",
    "key": 54321,
    "date": "26-06-2019"
  },
  {
    "title" : "Yet Some other title",
    "key": 98765,
    "date": "27-06-2019"
  }
]
```

**Remote Data**

```
let remoteData = [
    {
        "title": "My title",
        "key": 12345,
        "date": "28-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Some other title",
        "key": 54321,
        "date": "29-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Yet Some other title",
        "key": 98765,
        "date": "27-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Also Yet Some other title",
        "key": 47289,
        "date": "30-06-2019"
    }
]
```

So following will be my implementation

```
let localData = [
  {
    "title" : "My title",
    "key": 12345,
    "date": "25-06-2019" 
  },
  {
    "title" : "Some other title",
    "key": 54321,
    "date": "26-06-2019"
  },
  {
    "title" : "Yet Some other title",
    "key": 98765,
    "date": "27-06-2019"
  }
] ;

const getRemoteData = async() {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get('api_url')
    return response;
  } catch(err) {
    throw err
  }
}

const someFunction = async() {
  try {
    let remoteData = await getRemoteData()
    localData = compareData(remoteData, localData)
    // process with updated localData
  } catch(err) {
    handleError(err)
  }
}

const compareData = (remoteData, localData) => {
    let data = remoteData.map((remote_element) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < localData.length; i++) {
            let local_element = localData[i];
            if (local_element.key === remote_element.key) {
                if (local_element.date === remote_element.date) {
                    return local_element; // no need to update.
                } else {
                    return remote_element; // found diff dates. Update local data.
                }
            }
        }
        return remote_element; // Found new remote element insert into localData.
    })
    return data
}
```

The output will be combination of both updated data and local data.

```
[
    {
        "title": "My title",
        "key": 12345,
        "date": "28-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Some other title",
        "key": 54321,
        "date": "29-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Yet Some other title",
        "key": 98765,
        "date": "27-06-2019"
    },
    {
        "title": "Also Yet Some other title",
        "key": 47289,
        "date": "30-06-2019"
    }
]
```

Let me know if this was the case.